# Can't find a method declared in other java file

Tags: java

I'm Building a todo app, I declared methods in separate java file and when I wanna access them in another java file they are saying 'can't resolve the method'

You can see the whole project at https://github.com/RamcharanS/MyTODO_Be_Productive

Please Help me with this and if possible please check and give a small review on my code

Java file of Methods

```
package com.example.mytodo;

public class my_todo {
    String titledoes;
    String datedoes;
    String descdoes;
    String keydoes;

    public my_todo() {
    }

    public my_todo(String titledoes, String datedoes, String descdoes, String keydoes) {
        this.titledoes = titledoes;
        this.datedoes = datedoes;
        this.descdoes = descdoes;
        this.keydoes = keydoes;
    }



    public String getKeydoes() {
        return keydoes;
    }

    public void setKeydoes(String keydoes) {
        this.keydoes = keydoes;
    }

    public String getTitledoes() {
        return titledoes;
    }

    public void setTitledoes(String titledoes) {
        this.titledoes = titledoes;
    }

    public String getDatedoes() {
        return datedoes;
    }

    public void setDatedoes(String datedoes) {
        this.datedoes = datedoes;
    }

    public String getDescdoes() {
        return descdoes;
    }

    public void setDescdoes(String descdoes) {
        this.descdoes = descdoes;
    }
}
```

This is the Java file Giving me Error 
Method : getTitledoes() getDescdoes() getDatedoes()

```
package com.example.mytodo;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.mytodo.R;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DoesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DoesAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    Context context;
    ArrayList myDoes;

    public DoesAdapter(Context c, ArrayList p) {
        context = c;
        myDoes = p;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public  MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i){
    return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.new_todo, viewGroup, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i){
        MyViewHolder.titledoes.setText(myDoes.get(i).getTitledoes());
        MyViewHolder.descdoes.setText(myDoes.get(i).getDescdoes());
        MyViewHolder.datedoes.setText(myDoes.get(i).getDatedoes());
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return myDoes.size();
    }
    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView titledoes, descdoes, datedoes;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            titledoes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titledoes);
            descdoes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.descdoes);
            datedoes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.datedoes);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause for your problem is that you are using `ArrayList` without specifying generic type, this means that when you get element from list it will be `Object` and not `my_todo`, you can simply fix this problem by adding generic type which you want list to be:

change `ArrayList myDoes;` to `List<my_todo> myDoes;`

and constructor parameter to `List<my_todo> p`.

Note that I have used `List` instead of `ArrayList`, because it is more abstract type, its best practice to always use most abstract type that is possible in given situation.

**UPDATE:**

I would gladly explain you how generics work but that would result in quite long answer, seeing that you are beginner I would suggest to find some Java book or online course, most of those cover generics, how they work and how to use them, also you can read [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) from Oracle itself

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked but I didn't understand my error properly please help me to understand it

Answer (score 1):

Create your list like this

```
// modify your adapter class like this
  Context context;
 ArrayList<my_todo> myDoes;

public DoesAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<my_todo> p) {
    context = c;
    myDoes = p;
}


// create list in your activity
 ArrayList<my_todo> list=new ArrayList<>();
 list.add(new my_todo("title","date","desc","key"));

 // pass list  to adapter class
 new DoesAdapter(this,list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try declare your `ArrayList myDoes` as `ArrayList<my_todo>` myDoes and in your Adapter constructor parameter too. Only `ArrayList` you have an `ArrayList` of `Object` type.